# Merge results of string_split operations and update table

Tags: sql-server, split, resultset

I have a table with 3 columns: col1, col2, col3. I need to insert rows into this table and my inputs are 3 parameters, one int param and two varchar params that I need to split. So for example

```
@param1 = 1    
@param2 = '2,3'
@param3 = '4,5'
```

the rows to be produced are

```
1,2,4
1,3,5
```

I tried to get near the desired result with such code

```
WITH group1 AS (
  SELECT @param1 as col1, value as col2 from string_split(@param2,',')
),
group2 AS (
  SELECT @param1 as col1, value as col3 from string_split(@param3,',') 
)
SELECT group1.col1, group1.col2, group2.col3
  FROM group1
  JOIN group2 ON group1.col1 = group2.col1
```

but it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Do `@param2` and `@param3` always have 2 substrings?

Comment: no, they could have many and always equal number of substrings

Comment: which version of sql-server you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a splitter, that returns each substring and the position of the substring. Sometimes a JSON-based approach may help. You need to transform the comma-separated strings into valid JSON arrays (`2,3` into `[2,3]`), parse the arrays with `OPENJSON()` and use the appropriate `JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @param1 int = 1    
DECLARE @param2 varchar(100) = '2,3,6,8'
DECLARE @param3 varchar(100) = '4,5,9,5'

-- INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT 
   @param1 AS Column1,
   j1.[value] AS Column2, 
   j2.[value] AS Column3
FROM OPENJSON (CONCAT('[', @param2, ']')) j1
FULL JOIN OPENJSON (CONCAT('[', @param3, ']')) j2 ON j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Result:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       2       4
1       3       5
1       6       9
1       8       5
```

As an important note (although `STRING_SPLIT()` splits a string into rows and returns a table), as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) the *output rows might be in any order* and the *order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

Comment: Oh no, then i cannot use string_split in my scenario. Is there any other builtin function like string_split or do i have to create my own?

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou There are many examples here about how to split a string. And yes, you need to use an existing or create your own function.